# How to remove a web-element using in selenium using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Is there any way by which we can remove a web-element from the the source of the page.

I have the problem that there is a division of popup in the webpage source which is disabling all other divisions. If we remove this division while doing inspect element from a browser all other elements are automatically enabled for use.

How can I do this in selenium webdriver?

Comment: In general, it's a bad practice to modify the HTML of the page. Selenium was designed to interact with the page as a user would. What do you have to do manually to get to the elements that you want to interact with? Do that using code and you should be able to complete your scenario.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, there is no direct Java method, but you can use the [`JavaScriptExecutor`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) API to do something like:

```
WebElement yourElement = …
JavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavaScriptExecutor) webDriver;
jsExecutor.executeScript(
    "arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0])", yourElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Actually I have solved my problem by clicking on a webelement (OK button).

It worked for my case but wont work in general.